# migrating from EC2 to Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2

First of all, I have never used Amazon EC2 neither Windows Azure. But I have a task to move application from EC2 to Azure. App is a REST api written in node.js. Currently I know that there is one EC2 instance with ubuntu with runing app on it. App is deployed to server/instance using tool called `Capper`. App uses some database and redis. This api is used by mobile clients.

My question is what is the simplest way to move app from EC2 to Azure and what type of service to use on Azure for hosting such app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either deploy a Linux-based VM in Azure's "Virtual Machines".  Check this article out for assistance: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

Alternatively, you can deploy a node.js app on Windows Azure Websites, by adding a new "Web site" thru the management portal, and pick the node.js template from the gallery of predefined templates.

HTH

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure there is node.js hosting available on Azure.  If they don't actually care about Ubuntu and just need Node.js that might be easier: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

Comment: You're totally correct, I forgot that Azure Websites contain a template for Node.js website.  Depending on your app, you maybe able to host it there.  I'll edit my response

Comment: Hmm, but which of this two options (VM or Website) will be better for REST api? Which one is easier to scale / maintain? What are major differences?

Comment: Website is by far easier to maintain as it is fully managed by the Azure platform.  VM is a VM.. meaning, you have to fully manage it (patch/upgrade/configure/etc)